# Exponential of positive self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

In a physics paper I am currently reading, the following statement seems to be used: Let $A$ be a (not necessarily bounded) positive self-adjoint operator on $L^2(a,b)$ with $C_0^{\infty}(a,b)\subseteq \mathrm{dom}(A)$. Then $\Phi(t)=\cos(A^{1/2}t)$ is well-defined for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is this statment true? And if yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: Is it $\phi(t)=\cos(A^{1/2}t)$?

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer right now, but you should look into the Borel functional calculus. Not only is $\Phi(t)$ defined for all $t$, it extends to a bounded operator on $L^2(a,b)$ since $\cos$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. A reference I particularly like for material on operator algebras and functional analysis is Kadison and Ringrose's "Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras." Volume I is the appropriate one for this material.

Comment: What you are doing is nothing but an extension of the idea of [functions of matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) to bounded linear operators. Read under Cauchy Integral.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Spectral theorem for unbounded self-adjoint operators. See Michael E. Taylor's Partial Differential Equations Vol II page 97, equation (1.30) and Theorem 1.7. This is the Borel functional calculus mentioned above. Once you do square root and exponential, you can get to cosine. Also see the discussion in the second paragraph of page 98, which gives the boundedness of the operator.